# Programmatically Set Layout Params in Android v7.0 vs. Android 5.0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-version

**Background**

In my Android app, I add, remove, and manipulate elements of rows in a table programmatically. I need to set the layout parameters of elements in a TableRow() upon these table manipulation events.

**Problem**

After migrating from Android 5.0 to Android 7.0 and running the app on a different tablet, the table row's do not reflect the layout param's that are defined.

To clarify:

**Configuration 1:**

- Hardware: Samsung Galaxy Tab4
- Android Version: 5.0.2
- Result: Table row's formatted correctly

**Configuration 2**

- Hardware: Samsung Galaxy Tab S2
- Android Version: 7.0
- Result: Table row's not formatted

**Code Sample**

```
//Define Layout Parameters
rowLayoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
tableLayoutParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
editTextLayoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(100, 40);
tvLayoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

//Create new table tow
tableRow = new TableRow(getActivity());
tableRow.setLayoutParams(rowLayoutParams);

//Define Margins
int etMargin1 = (int)getActivity().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.etMargin1);
int etMargin2 = (int)getActivity().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.etMargin2);

int tvMargin1 = (int)getActivity().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.tvMargin1);
int tvMargin2 = (int)getActivity().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.tvMargin2);


if(editable)
{
    //Create Edit Texts
    EditText exampleEt = new EditText(getActivity());
    editTextLayoutParams.setMargins(etMargin1,5,etMargin2,5);
    exampleEt.setLayoutParams(editTextLayoutParams);
    tableRow.setLayoutParams(rowLayoutParams);
    tableRow.addView(exampleEt);
}
else
{
    //Create Text Views
    TextView exampleTv = new TextView(getActivity());

    //Set Layout Params
    tvLayoutParams.setMargins(tvMargin1,5,tvMargin2,5);
    exampleTv.setLayoutParams(tvLayoutParams);

    tableRow.setLayoutParams(rowLayoutParams);
    tableRow.addView(exampleTv);
}
```

**Further Specification**

Note in the code sample the Edit Text's vs. the Text Views.  It is only the Edit Text elements that do not get formatted properly.  The Text View margins format as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a 2 part solution that revolved around the different screen sizes of the tablets.  The android version was not a factor.

**Part 1** was to define the row layout width and height parameters in terms of density independent pixels rather than hard-coded values

```
int etHeight = (int)getActivity().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.etHeight);
int etWidth = (int)getActivity().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.etWidth);

editTextLayoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(etWidth, etHeight);
```

where in dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="etHeight">40dp</dimen>
<dimen name="etWidth">100dp</dimen>
```

**Part 2** was to change the table width dimension referenced by the xml table definition in the layout file.  The margins were in fact formatting correctly, but the table was too large for the screen and created the illusion that the elements were packed to the left side of the table.

The question now is whether to design the layout for a smaller tablet and waste screen space on the larger tablet, or create multiple layout/dimension files that support different tablet sizes.  But, that is a topic for a different thread.